# VoIP calls ending automatically [flutter_webrtc]

Tags: flutter, dart, webrtc, flutter-webrtc, matrix-org

I am working on a Flutter app that utilizes VoIP functionality using the flutter_webRTC package. When attempting to make a group call using `VoIP.newGroupCall`, The call is created and when entering a call, it  is getting initiated but ends automatically without any user interaction.

Sample code:

```
VoIP.newGroupCall(
  roomId,
  GroupCallType.Video,
  GroupCallIntent.Ring,
);
```

followed by
groupCall.enter();

```
// VoIP delegate methods
@override
Future<void> handleNewGroupCall(GroupCall groupCall) async {
  logger.i("NEW GROUP CALL STARTED");
}

@override
Future<void> handleGroupCallEnded(GroupCall groupCall) async {
  logger.i("NEW GROUP CALL ENDED");
}
```

I have verified that the `handleNewGroupCall` method is being called, indicating that the call is initiated successfully. However, shortly after, the `handleGroupCallEnded` method is triggered automatically, indicating that the call ends abruptly.

How can I diagnose and fix this issue to ensure that group calls are not ended automatically?